# What is RSL (Runtime shared library ) used for in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Kindly note I am not asking what SWCs are used for, I know about that.

I want to know, the use of RSLs in flash. Say i have some useful classes which i currently am using by specifying the particular folder as an "Additional source folder".

So, can i make use of RSL here. If not, when and why i need to use RSLs ( I use SWCs without any problem, but i wanna know how to make use of RSL, without making SWCs, ie just by bunch of actionscript classes )

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest reading Adobe's Introduction to RSLs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html

> One way to reduce the size of your applications’ SWF files is by
>   externalizing shared assets into stand-alone files that can be
>   separately downloaded and cached on the client. These shared assets
>   can be loaded and used by any number of applications at run time, but
>   are transferred only once to the client. These shared files are known
>   as Runtime Shared Libraries or RSLs.
>
> When multiple applications share a core set of components or classes,
>   clients can download those assets only once as an RSL rather than once
>   for each application. The RSLs are persisted on the client disk so
>   that they do not need to be transferred across the network a second
>   time. The resulting file size for the applications can be reduced. The
>   benefits increase as the number of applications that use the RSL
>   increases.